# Use IIFE capability in $scope to create transformed data on page load

Tags: angularjs, scope, iife

I am relatively new to JavaScript & Angular. 
So this may be a dumb question, but here goes ...

I need to execute a function that will perform data transformation on incoming data and create arrays & objects that the page will consume. I can only process my page after this function is executed.

Please note that this function will not be used directly by any angular artifact, but its output will.

Please advise. Thanks

```
$scope.prepped_data = function (data) {
    // code to generate new data structures //
    $scope.data1 = {};
    $scope.data2 = {};
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a factory like this:

```
angular.module('yourAppModule').factory('yourFactory', function ($http) {
return {
    getData: function() {
        var url = 'http://get-your-data.com/data';
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: url
        });
    },
}
```

And afterwards, in the controller:

```
angular.module('yourAppModule').controller('yourCtrl', function ($scope, yourFactory) {
        yourFactory.getData().success(function (data) {
        // process your data here
        $scope.data = dataProcessed;
    }
});
```

You can then use "data" in your view to display it as you wish, there are also filtering capabilities in [Angular templates](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter). Take a look.

If you need a custom function to be used in the view, you may pass it to the $scope in your controller, kinnda like you did.

```
$scope.myFunc = function(data){
   //code here
}
```

And then in your view, you may use:

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" ng-app="yourAppModule" id="ng-app">
  <head>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="yourCtrl">
      {{ myFunc() }}
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps,
Best.

Comment: Thx. Will try this.So, on my page I should invoke the function as soon as I declare the controller, right? I am currently not actually retrieving the data from the server 'yet', but declaring it as $scope.data1 = [] in my controller.

Comment: Sure, you can declare a closure within your controller and use it at your will to process the data before sending it to the view.

Comment: Okay, can you provide an example? The manual invocation you described worked, why is the closure approach better? Thx

Comment: You can process the data in the callback of "getData()", or in the controller itself, or create a closure, as you wish, but i think it's always cleaner to have your data processing in the controller in order to keep the "view" strictly for UI purposes.

Answer (score 0):

In the service

```
  public method1(){
        var defer = this.$q.defer();
           //Show some loader 
        this.$http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: "www.xyz.com"
        }).success((result) => {
            //Hide loader 
           defer.resolve(result);
        }).error((result) => {
            defer.reject(result);
        });
```

In the controller

```
         method1().then(function(data){//Do your processing})
```

Comment: thx for the response. However, as I have not started work on the http section (I am stubbing incoming data in my controller), is there a way to still to make my controller work  to continue controller dev and unit testing?